# Fill Pyspark dataframe column null values with average value from same column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

With a dataframe like this,

```
rdd_2 = sc.parallelize([(0,10,223,"201601"), (0,10,83,"2016032"),(1,20,None,"201602"),(1,20,3003,"201601"), (1,20,None,"201603"), (2,40, 2321,"201601"), (2,30, 10,"201602"),(2,61, None,"201601")])

df_data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_2, ["id", "type", "cost", "date"])
df_data.show()

+---+----+----+-------+
| id|type|cost|   date|
+---+----+----+-------+
|  0|  10| 223| 201601|
|  0|  10|  83|2016032|
|  1|  20|null| 201602|
|  1|  20|3003| 201601|
|  1|  20|null| 201603|
|  2|  40|2321| 201601|
|  2|  30|  10| 201602|
|  2|  61|null| 201601|
+---+----+----+-------+
```

I need to fill the null values with the average of the existing values, with the expected result being

```
+---+----+----+-------+
| id|type|cost|   date|
+---+----+----+-------+
|  0|  10| 223| 201601|
|  0|  10|  83|2016032|
|  1|  20|1128| 201602|
|  1|  20|3003| 201601|
|  1|  20|1128| 201603|
|  2|  40|2321| 201601|
|  2|  30|  10| 201602|
|  2|  61|1128| 201601|
+---+----+----+-------+
```

where `1128` is the average of the existing values. I need to do that for several columns.

My current approach is to use `na.fill`:

```
fill_values = {column: df_data.agg({column:"mean"}).flatMap(list).collect()[0] for column in df_data.columns if column not in ['date','id']}
df_data = df_data.na.fill(fill_values)

+---+----+----+-------+
| id|type|cost|   date|
+---+----+----+-------+
|  0|  10| 223| 201601|
|  0|  10|  83|2016032|
|  1|  20|1128| 201602|
|  1|  20|3003| 201601|
|  1|  20|1128| 201603|
|  2|  40|2321| 201601|
|  2|  30|  10| 201602|
|  2|  61|1128| 201601|
+---+----+----+-------+
```

But this is very cumbersome. Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, one way or another you have to:

- compute statistics
- fill the blanks

It pretty much limits what you can really improve here, still:

- replace `flatMap(list).collect()[0]` with `first()[0]` or structure unpacking
- compute all stats with a single action
- use built-in `Row` methods to extract dictionary

The final result could like this:

```
def fill_with_mean(df, exclude=set()): 
    stats = df.agg(*(
        avg(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns if c not in exclude
    ))
    return df.na.fill(stats.first().asDict())

fill_with_mean(df_data, ["id", "date"])
```

In Spark 2.2 or later you can also use `Imputer`. See [Replace missing values with mean - Spark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40059453/1560062).

Comment: @Kevad do import pyspark.sql.functions as fn, then use fn.avg

Comment: Did someone improve this function ? Take way too much computing time on my side !? :)

Comment: @NicoCoallier Performance-wise you won't get any significant improvement. This is pretty much optimal solution. API-wise you can use `Imputer`.

Comment: Is it faster to exclude or include ?

Comment: @NicoCoallier This has negligible impact, but If you're doing this on large number of columns (like thousands) , optimizer overhead alone is significant. If this is the case `RDD` might be faster. Of course, a lot depends on what you mean by slow...

Comment: My master keep crash at this line , however when I reduce the number of data it works

Comment: Slow ~ more than an hour

Comment: @NicoCoallier Well, then try to determine the bottleneck. If the cluster is mostly idle then it is likely to be planner. In case like this you can try with `RDDs`, NumPy and `StatCounter`. If the tasks are slow, then it is either configuration problem, or lack of resources.

Comment: When I increase the worker or the partitioning it get slower

Comment: Do you have an example from DF to RDD, fillna and then back to DF ?

Comment: Is there a way without udf ?

Comment: @NicoCoallier You can try something around these lines https://stackoverflow.com/a/35585532/1560062 UDF is not applicable here at all.